# Есть ли в Telethon некий event, чтобы повесить на него реакцию на изменение прав пользователя?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

К примеру, есть такое:

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(func=lambda event: event.is_group))
```

А есть ли что-то, что отслеживает *изменение прав пользователя*. Например, когда пользователя назначили администратором, или лишили некоторых прав, или объявили мут? Типа:

```
@client.on(events.ChangeUserPermission(func=lambda event: event.is_group))
```

Заранее благодарю за ответы! Документацию и яндексы прилежно читал, но похоже опыта не хватает объять необъятное